# Combine two finals into one for Tweens?

Tags: flutter, dart

This might be an incredibly stupid question but can you combine two finals together to create one?

Here is my code:

```
  final _avatarAlignTween =
      AlignmentTween(begin: Alignment.bottomLeft, end: Alignment.topCenter);
  
  final _textSizeTween = TextStyleTween(
    begin: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontSize: 33.0),
    end: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 23.0),
  );
```

Basically I want it to be something like this just without the plus as this won't work (effectively I want it to do these things at the same time):

```
  final _avatarAlignTween =
      AlignmentTween(begin: Alignment.bottomLeft, end: Alignment.topCenter) +
  TextStyleTween(
    begin: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
        fontSize: 33.0),
    end: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
        fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
        fontSize: 23.0),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one AnimationController to drive both of the Tween

Here is the example-

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
          home: MyApp(),
        ));
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      AnimationController _animationController;
      Animation<Alignment> _avatarAlignAnimation;
    
      Animation<TextStyle> _textSizeAnimation;
      @override
      void initState() {
        _animationController =
            AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200));
        _textSizeAnimation = TextStyleTween(
          begin: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              fontSize: 33.0),
          end: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.red,
              fontFamily: 'AvenirNext',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 23.0),
        ).animate(_animationController);
        _avatarAlignAnimation =
            AlignmentTween(begin: Alignment.bottomLeft, end: Alignment.topCenter)
                .animate(_animationController);
        //To Start the animation
        _animationController.forward();  
        _animationController.addListener(() {
         setState(() {});
        });
        super.initState();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Align(
              alignment: _avatarAlignAnimation.value,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "title",
                    style: _textSizeAnimation.value,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

}
```